# Content div not extending as far as possible

Tags: html, web

So what seems to be the problem is my content div is not extending all the way down the page. The width is just how I want it, but the bottom seems to hover or get stuck in the middle of the page. This causes my footer to stick to the bottom of the content div as well. What can I do to fix this? I know there are a lot of questions like this one, but none of the answers seem to be working for me.

****<---HTML--->****

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Stan Mattingly</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="personalStyle.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p id = "logo">Stan Mattingly</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">About</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">Home</p>
        </a> 



    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Click A Link To Get Started.</h1>
        <div id = "social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DontMakeYourArmsFallOff">
                <img src="facebook button.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/StanMattingly">
                <img src="twitter logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="http://soundcloud.com/djmicrocrush">
                <img src="soundcloud logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.hudl.com/athlete/2671311/stan-mattingly">
                <img src="hudle logo.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>This is 100% designed and created by yours truly.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**<---CSS--->**

```
#header
{
    background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -10px -20px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;

}
#logo
{
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.button
{
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#content
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    height: 100%;
    width: 85%;
    margin: -9px auto -15px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;


}
#social
{
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    display: inline-block;

}
#footer
{
    background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;

}
body, html{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-image: url("stars.jpg");


}
*
{
    font-family: Segoe Script;
}

#header a:link
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:hover 
{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black  
}

#content a:link
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:hover 
{
    color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
}
#footer a:link
{
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover 
{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your content div will extend as far as it needs to extend, depending on how much "content" is in your content div. For example if I place a paragraph in the content div, it will extend as long as the paragraph makes it extend. Please check the code below with a paragraph inserted in the content div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Stan Mattingly</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="personalStyle.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p id = "logo">Stan Mattingly</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">About</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">Home</p>
        </a> 



    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non dapibus turpis, ac tincidunt eros. Nullam eget facilisis est. Nam at malesuada nunc. Duis metus arcu, iaculis at dapibus eu, semper suscipit diam. Pellentesque pellentesque nec libero et fringilla. Praesent pharetra placerat felis, tempor laoreet urna accumsan ac. Vivamus iaculis, odio nec pulvinar varius, magna dui interdum diam, nec blandit ligula justo ac quam. Fusce tempor, velit eu fringilla consequat, metus ante molestie tortor, ac volutpat nisi leo non nulla. Etiam sed nunc non magna porttitor sodales vel id ligula. Cras porta enim lorem, in pulvinar est dictum non. Cras ut dui fringilla sapien porta dictum. Proin egestas fermentum libero, nec tincidunt velit fringilla at. Cras lacinia ligula vehicula egestas interdum. Proin feugiat urna ligula, sodales gravida sem accumsan sed. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc eros lorem, varius at lobortis ut, vehicula id metus. Donec at tellus at urna eleifend auctor. Fusce vitae orci risus. Quisque convallis ut orci in commodo. Nulla nec tellus non sem adipiscing tristique a sed nisi. Aenean arcu elit, condimentum non odio sit amet, tincidunt consectetur dolor. Ut lorem elit, lacinia nec justo eu, sodales aliquet nulla. Morbi luctus in nunc quis molestie. Maecenas ut bibendum quam. Integer rhoncus viverra ligula et lacinia. Pellentesque augue magna, imperdiet quis nulla vel, congue dignissim justo. Etiam ut vulputate nibh, et lobortis neque. Vestibulum pellentesque orci ut eros posuere, quis malesuada purus vestibulum. Aenean ultricies justo faucibus eros ultrices, sed vestibulum sem luctus. Nam pulvinar, quam in rhoncus facilisis, urna dui blandit magna, nec auctor quam orci eu eros. Ut et justo nisi. Duis ligula lectus, pulvinar eget dui a, porttitor congue risus. Donec ac eros eleifend, faucibus ipsum molestie, lacinia augue. Fusce suscipit quis nunc fermentum posuere. Integer gravida scelerisque mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a eros mi. Morbi molestie, dolor id pellentesque venenatis, nunc quam venenatis felis, at sollicitudin nisi lectus id lectus. Vestibulum quis vulputate purus, in varius arcu. Donec ut massa tellus. Ut fringilla nisl tempus mi tincidunt scelerisque. Sed sit amet egestas elit, vitae vestibulum nisl. Etiam suscipit commodo varius. Nullam bibendum orci felis, vitae suscipit risus pharetra id. Etiam nec convallis ipsum. Nullam facilisis mi eget nulla pulvinar, at placerat risus malesuada. Nullam id est nulla. Proin aliquet est dui, ut sollicitudin mauris condimentum eget. Nam dictum arcu id venenatis lacinia. Donec vel mi sit amet ipsum adipiscing rhoncus. Phasellus blandit vestibulum nisl ac fringilla. Vestibulum metus augue, auctor vitae accumsan a, bibendum at elit. Proin erat purus, placerat sed cursus vel, placerat ac erat. Pellentesque id egestas enim, ac vehicula tellus. </p>
        <h1>Click A Link To Get Started.</h1>
        <div id = "social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DontMakeYourArmsFallOff">
                <img src="facebook button.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/StanMattingly">
                <img src="twitter logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="http://soundcloud.com/djmicrocrush">
                <img src="soundcloud logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.hudl.com/athlete/2671311/stan-mattingly">
                <img src="hudle logo.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>This is 100% designed and created by yours truly.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Little Change in CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
        #header
    {
        background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
        height: 60px;

        width: 85%;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 150px;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
    #logo
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .button
    {
        float: right;
        margin: auto;
        margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
    }

    #content
    {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        height: 100%;
        width: 85%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;


    }
    #social
    {
        padding: 40px;
        margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
        display: inline-block;

    }
    #footer
    {
        background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
        height: 45px;
        width: 85%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        clear: both;

    }
    body, html{
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        background-image: url("stars.jpg");


    }
    *
    {
        font-family: Segoe Script;
    }

    #header a:link
    {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #header a:hover 
    {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #header a:visited
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black  
    }

    #content a:link
    {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #content a:hover 
    {
        color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #content a:visited
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white; 
    }
    #footer a:link
    {
       color: black;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    #footer a:hover 
    {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #footer a:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black  }
    *.cImg
       {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p id = "logo">Stan Mattingly</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">About</p>
        </a>
        <a href="PersonalHome.html">
            <p class = "button">Home</p>
        </a> 



    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Click A Link To Get Started.</h1>
        <div id = "social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DontMakeYourArmsFallOff">
                <img src="facebook button.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/StanMattingly">
                <img src="twitter logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="http://soundcloud.com/djmicrocrush">
                <img src="soundcloud logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.hudl.com/athlete/2671311/stan-mattingly">
                <img src="hudle logo.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>This is 100% designed and created by yours truly.</p>
    </div>
```

I don't know what u mean exactly, but test that and tell me back what u want exactly. I will help u.

Comment: I simply want my content div to extend all the way down. Right now the bottom of it is not going far enough. The page is essentially scrunched

Comment: So,Add One Paragraph before content Div and recheck that. that will be down at that time.I edited my answer, pls check.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header
{
    background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -10px -20px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;

}
#logo
{
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.button
{
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#content
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    height: 80%;
    width: 98%;
    margin: -9px auto -15px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;


}
#social
{
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    display: inline-block;


}
#footer
{
    background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    padding-top:40%


}
body, html{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-image: url("stars.jpg");


}
*
{
    font-family: Segoe Script;
}

#header a:link
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:hover 
{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black  
}

#content a:link
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:hover 
{
    color: rgba(225,225,225,.6);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
}
#footer a:link
{
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover 
{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black  
}
```

Comment: I had set the position:absolute; in style sheet for content div. Please check and let me know how does it look and does it work for you.